# How to exclude an entire PO based on the combination of multiple line items using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, one-to-many

I have a scenario where we have two systems that both contain PO's which are related - one is a global system and one is local.  I need to write 2 queries that show 1: Cancelled in the global system but NOT in the local system and 2. Cancelled in the local system but NOT in the global system.  The tricky part is the global system will always only have 1 line item and its status is either 90 for cancelled or 10 for active.  The related PO on the local side can have multiple line items and if any one of them is active the PO is active.  I wrote the below SQL for the first scenario and it works great because if any single PO line item on the local side is active, the PO is active.  Now I need to do the reverse of that and I am having trouble as I am not sure how to say "only when all lines are closed, the PO is closed" - any thoughts.  Appreciate the help and still learning how to use tags. "L" on the local side is the code for line is deleted - blank would be active.

the query for the first scenario which works is:

```
SELECT G.order_no AS 'GPS_ORDER_#', 
       G.order_status AS 'GPS_ORDER_STATUS', 
       G.cst_order_no AS 'GPS_CUSTOMER_PO_#',
       H.PO_NUMBER AS 'SAP_PO_#',
       P.PO_ITEM_NUMBER, 
       P.DEL_INDICATOR
  FROM (SELECT order_no, 
               order_status, 
               cst_order_no
          FROM asagdwpdx_prod.dbo.SimoxOrder1
         UNION ALL
        SELECT order_no, 
               order_status, 
               cst_order_no
          FROM asagdwpdx_prod.dbo.SimoxOrder2
         UNION ALL 
        SELECT order_no, 
               order_status, 
               cst_order_no
          FROM asagdwpdx_prod.dbo.SimoxOrder3) G 
  JOIN PDX_SAP_USER.dbo.VW_PO_HEADER H 
    ON G.order_no = H.AHAG_NUMBER
  JOIN PDX_SAP_USER.dbo.VW_PO_ITEM P 
    ON H.PO_NUMBER = P.PO_NUMBER 
 WHERE G.order_status = '90'
   AND   P.DEL_INDICATOR <> 'L';
```

Comment: Will a global PO always have at least 1 matching local PO?

Comment: Count the number of lines for a PO, and count the number of 'closed' lines for a PO.  If they're equal, the PO is closed.

Comment: yes - the global PO always has just one line - the local is more granular and splits the same values into more than one line sometimes.

Comment: I can totally count the number of lines on the PO I was curious how to count only the deleted lines

Comment: DEL_INDICATOR = 'L' meaning closed or cancelled?

Comment: L indicates that the line is deleted - when all lines are deleted on the local side then the PO would be considered cancelled.  That is the main issue - if even one line is active the PO is considered active so just checking seems to be producing incorrect results I need to somehow group them as one - where one is open basically the whole PO is open. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

step 1 :

```
SELECT ... CASE WHEN DEL_INDICATOR = 'L' THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS DEL_INDICATOR_BOOL
```

step 2 :

```
... GROUP BY P.PO_NUMBER HAVING BOOL_AND(DEL_INDICATOR_BOOL) == FALSE
```

in words :

may use group by + having + aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

If a global PO always has at least 1 matching local PO, then you can perform a subquery on the local POs where the status is active and join it, then look for a null value for the local PO. Without comments, I'm not going to try to change your query, but it would look something like:

```
SELECT
    global_table.po
FROM global_table
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        PO
    FROM local_table
    WHERE local_table.po_status = 90    --Looking for any active POs
    ) AS local_table ON
    global_table.po = local_table.po    --Join those active POs
WHERE local_table.po IS NULL    --Exclude any POs that had an active record in the local table
```

Answer (score 0):

you check the value of del_indicator if all are 'L' by using the CASE statement in the below's query

```
SELECT g.order_no AS 'gps_order_#', 
       g.order_status AS 'gps_order_status', 
       g.cst_order_no AS 'gps_customer_po_#',
       l.po_number AS 'sap_po_#',
       l.po_item_number, 
       l.del_indicator
  FROM (SELECT order_no, 
               order_status, 
               cst_order_no
          FROM asagdwpdx_prod.dbo.simoxorder1
         UNION ALL
        SELECT order_no, 
               order_status, 
               cst_order_no
          FROM asagdwpdx_prod.dbo.simoxorder2
         UNION ALL 
        SELECT order_no, 
               order_status, 
               cst_order_no
          FROM asagdwpdx_prod.dbo.simoxorder3) g
  JOIN (SELECT h.ahag_number,
               h.po_number,
               i.po_item_number, 
               i.del_indicator,
               CASE WHEN MIN(i.del_indicator) = MAX(i.del_indicator) 
                     AND MIN(i.del_indicator) = 'L'
                    THEN 'closed'
                    ELSE 'active'
                END local_o_status
          FROM pdx_sap_user.dbo.vw_po_header h
          JOIN pdx_sap_user.dbo.vw_po_item i
            ON h.po_number = i.po_number
         GROUP BY h.ahag_number,
                  h.po_number,
                  i.po_item_number, 
                  i.del_indicator) l
    ON g.order_no = l.ahag_number
 WHERE g.order_status = '10'
   AND l.local_o_status = 'closed'
```

Comment: I do feel like that is on the right track but getting the aggregate/group by error:

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
Column 'pdx_sap_user.dbo.vw_po_header.AHAG_NUMBER' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I was able to group by the SELECT fields in the JOIN and get it to work - the issue is it still brings back PO's with mixed line status - line 1 not deleted line 2 is deleted...not sure what to do but appreciate the help not sure if I can post a screencap but I could show you what I mean